# C++ Error: identifier "CWnd" is not defined

Tags: c++, mfc, cwnd

I'm very much a C++ newbie, so please bear with me.

This line of code which resides within a function:

```
CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
```

`CWnd` is coming up as "undefined". I know I need to define it in the global scope, but how? What header do I need to include to use this class? Project is MFC.

Using VS 2010.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to solve this problem independently.

First, [Google](http://www.google.com) for "cwnd"

Second, click the [first link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xb05f0h(v=vs.80).aspx).

Third, read the page

> **Requirements**
>
> Header: `afxwin.h`

Comment: From the location where i am connecting: Now, this is the first page!

Comment: Link to Microsoft website is dead, should just keep the helpful part of the answer.